# posting a JSON request in Unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how to post a json request to the server in unity.

For example:

my URL is:  http://www.neurobic.com/services/scoreupload.svc/json/GetGameConfigurationLite

I need to get profile of the logged in player and this service requires a few parameters to be passed. For example.

```
j.AddField ("Id", "1234567890");
j.AddField ("MagicKey", ApplicationServices.magicKey); 
j.AddField ("RequestedBy", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
j.AddField ("Timestamp", "/Date(1547535370953)/"); 
j.AddField ("RequestSource", 1);
j.AddField ("RequestedGameId", "375b43c0-91be-e011-a505-001aa020d699"); 
j.AddField ("RequestedPersonId", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
```

This service responds with a JSON with the information based on the parameters of the posted request.

So how should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WWWForm Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html).

It should look something like this.

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(PostIt());
}
private IEnumerator PostIt() {
    WWWForm j = new WWWForm();
    j.AddField("Id", "1234567890");
    j.AddField("MagicKey", ApplicationServices.magicKey);
    j.AddField("RequestedBy", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
    j.AddField("Timestamp", "/Date(1547535370953)/");
    j.AddField("RequestSource", 1);
    j.AddField("RequestedGameId", "375b43c0-91be-e011-a505-001aa020d699");
    j.AddField("RequestedPersonId", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
    WWW www = new WWW("http://www.neurobic.com/services/scoreupload.svc/json/GetGameConfigurationLite", j);
    yield
    return www;
    Debug.Log(www.text); // => Json Response
}
```

Comment: OK I tried this and it is returning an error: 500 Internal Server Error